# VCOMP100.dll missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I' m trying to install VS2012 on a new computer and when I have created an executable release, an error dialog box is displayed:

```
The program can't start because VCCOMP100.DLL is missing from your computer... Try reinstalling the program!
```

It's really not about the reinstallation of the program and I'm not ready to do everything again after setting up the whole environment.

Any idea where to get that dll file?

PS: When having a look [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235624.aspx), it avers that it's coming from the OpenMP. But it's supposed to be included in VS2012?

Comment: What does Google say? Do you need to install additional runtime-packages?

Comment: Google say nothing about it!

Comment: http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?vcomp100

Comment: @Naresh Does Microsoft provide that dll? Can we trust such websites?

Comment: i scanned the file, there were no issues with it.

Comment: @Naresh Thanks ! If you could then answer the question below.

Comment: Isn't it better to generally install the actual full runtime package this file is a part of?

Answer (score 9):

Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) (x86 or x64 version, as appropriate for your system).  Better not to put mystery DLLs of unknown origin or intent on your system.